# Replace PHP String

Tags: php

I have a php String like below
"published-on-February-5--9785"

I want to replace that like "published-on-February59785",

Please note "-" is replaced only if it present before number.

Thanks
Sougata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex replace which called `preg_replace` in PHP

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

```
 preg_replace ( string|array $pattern , string|array $replacement , string|array $subject , int $limit = -1 , int &$count = null ) : string|array|null
```

this is the full definition, but we can focus on the first 3 parameter, which are `preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $subject)` the `$subject` is easy, which is just the input

For the other parameter you need a bit of understanding of regex if you aren't yet. For the particular case of removing `-` if it's present before a number, I think you can use `/\-+([0-9]+)/`

The `/` is just a delimiter or something, since PHP need the delimiter when using regex. A `+` symbol means having at least 1 or more, of the character stated before them, `\-` is just an escaped `-` since `-` is used in regex syntax and then `[0-9]` means that the character can be between character '0' until '9' (in the ASCII), which basically means a digit. The parenthesis symbol is just for grouping so you can use this later for replacing the string. So `/\-+([0-9]+)/` means match all of `-` that is followed by any amount of digit.

For the `$replacement` parameter, we will use `$1` which basically means group number 1 (the group being what's matched in the `[0-9]+` which are the digits).

The final result is

```
preg_replace("/\-+([0-9]+)/", "$1", $string);
```

See it in a fiddle: https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3c7a6135ecf0df57d8d3c5db87f76a8d7451f93e

You can learn more about regex in many articles online, you can also play around using this website: https://regex101.com